# Try .. catch and scope of file handles

Tags: ocaml

I currently have the following code

```
    let some_funct() = 
    (
        let handle = open_in "Myfle.dat" in

        try     
             ...
             ...    

        with e -> 
           close_in_noerr handle;
           raise e ;
    );;
```

The code works fine. The only problem is that my program terminates when the file "Myfle.dat" is missing. The reason for that I believe is that the open_in method is not being called inside the `try` statement. If I move that statement under the try block then the `handle` variable is not visible inside `with e` block. I am not sure how to solve this problem. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either check for a file existence before trying to open it, or use two nested `try/catch`. It is even better to use `with_file` function, that will accept a file name as well as a function that will be invoked on an opened channel. The `with_file` function will guarantee that the resource will be freed in any case. It is not a part of standard libraries, but is available in extended standard libraries (such as Janestreet Core Library), or can be easily written manually.